# How to execute multiple stored procedures at the same time?

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, execute

I have 3 procedures, how can I start executing all these procedures at same time?

Example :

```
 Proc A, Proc B, Proc C
```

I want to execute `A, B, C`  immediately, in parallel, not execute `A` and then after it finishes execute `B` and so on...

I mean I want to execute all procedures in parallel

Comment: This might help: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1500051-391-1.aspx

Comment: create separate SQL Jobs for each procedure and configure the time